# How to implement the airplane mode in app

Tags: android, airplane-mode

As you know, there is Airplane Mode feature setting in Android. 
if you execute this feature you can't use the data, internet, calling, messing and so on. How can I implement a Airplane Mode feature in app?

- I want to not be able to use the Internet, data, calling, messing from my App.

Like Airplane Mode.

Answer (score 2):

Please add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

and in code from [this BLOG](http://dustinbreese.blogspot.in/2009/04/andoid-controlling-airplane-mode.html)

**Check to see if it is enabled or not:**

```
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
      context.getContentResolver(), 
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
```

**To toggle it:**

```
// toggle airplane mode
Settings.System.putInt(
      context.getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**To get notifications on state change:**

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE");

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
      }
}

context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I did sign up yesterday.  so i don't know how to accept your answer.     please tell me how.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>

the error occurs -  ' Permission is only granted to system apps '